# aws s3 bucket not created using postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, postman

I am trying to create an s3-bucket in my aws account using postman. see below screenshot

[image]

I just pass **Host:divyeshjjjjjj.s3.amazonaws.com** in header and in Authorization see below image.

[image]

and body as none. but every time i requesting it is giving me below response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
    <Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
    <BucketName>divyeshjjjjjj</BucketName>
    <RequestId>FD3A666A6D53532F</RequestId>
    <HostId>TggknsaHzbwQi3y+k0hPCRAWq+z2XOGDrc7SX+ucvLQ2uuOIbHzYnfFClhwMyS09Q2WvDA2pBsE=</HostId>
</Error>
```

i am surfing from past 2 days don't know what problem is? please, help if you can!

Comment: No need to add `HTTP/1.1` in the URL bar.

Comment: okay...I tried both ways(with and without).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL line should always have `/` while creating a bucket, nothing else. In your case, it's `doc/2003-06-01`. It seems you are trying to create a folder/object in your bucket. We can't have nested buckets in S3.

Comment: okay...bucket created. but, while I delete it I get "Access Denied" error.

Comment: Your user doesn't have appropriate permissions perhaps.